# Balance Sheet Analysis with SimFin Data

Tags: r, dplyr, quantitative-finance

I wanted to analyse Financial Key Figures with R, using data from SimFin.

`MSFT_FY_Raw <- simfinR_get_fin_statements(59265, type_statements = 'pl', periods = 'FY', years = 2009:2020, api_key = simfin_api_key)`

The arguments are

- SimFinID (Company ID) - above 59265
- type_statements =

  - 'pl' (profit / loss)
  - 'bs'  (balance sheet)
  - 'cf' (Cash Flow)
- periods

  - 'FY' (fiscal year, only for 'pl' and 'cf')
  - c('Q4')  (for 'bs' to get the full year)
- years    2009:2020
- api_key  A personal api_key from SimFin

The output looks like this

```
Rows: 696
Columns: 13
$ company_name   <chr> "MICROSOFT CORP", "MICROSOFT CORP", "MICROSOFT CORP", "~
$ company_sector <chr> "Application Software", "Application Software", "Applic~
$ type_statement <fct> pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl, pl,~
$ period         <fct> FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY, FY,~
$ year           <int> 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2~
$ ref_date       <date> 2009-12-31, 2009-12-31, 2009-12-31, 2009-12-31, 2009-1~
$ acc_name       <chr> "Revenue", "Sales & Services Revenue", "Financing Reven~
$ acc_value      <dbl> 5.8437e+10, NA, NA, NA, -1.2155e+10, NA, NA, NA, 4.6282~**
$ tid            <chr> "1", "3", "5", "6", "2", "7", "8", "9", "4", "10", "11"~
$ uid            <chr> "1", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "4", "10", "11"~
$ parent_tid     <chr> "4", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "19", "19", "19~
$ display_level  <chr> "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", ~
$ check_possible <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,~
```

The interesting information is hidden in the *acc_name* and *acc_value* columns
So I extract that with dplyr and expand the columns

```
MSFT_PL <- pivot_wider(MSFT_1, names_from = acc_name, values_from = acc_value)
```

When doing this for the PL statement, this works fine.
The result looks like

```
> glimpse(MSFT_PL)
Rows: 12
Columns: 59
$ year                                          <int> 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, ~
$ Revenue                                       <dbl> 5.84370e+10, 6.24840e+10~
$ `Sales & Services Revenue`                    <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Financing Revenue`                           <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Other Revenue`                               <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Cost of revenue`                             <dbl> -1.2155e+10, -1.2395e+10~
$ `Cost of Goods & Services`                    <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Cost of Financing Revenue`                   <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Cost of Other Revenue`                       <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
$ `Gross Profit`                                <dbl> 4.6282e+10, 5.0089e+10, ~
$ `Other Operating Income`                      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ~
```

But if I do this for the Balance Sheet; even the unprocessed data does seem to have the same structure the expansion step fails here. Honestly I do not really understand the warning message. I cannot see any double data..

```
Warning:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

Now the Data is organised in lists. These lists I cannot use for plotting with ggplot.

```
> glimpse(MSFT_BS)
Rows: 12
Columns: 78
$ year                                              <int> 2009, 2010, 2011, 20~
$ `Cash, Cash Equivalents & Short Term Investments` <list> 3.1447e+10, 3.6788e~
$ `Cash & Cash Equivalents`                         <list> 6.076e+09, 5.505e+0~
$ `Short Term Investments`                          <list> 2.5371e+10, 3.1283e~
$ `Accounts & Notes Receivable`                     <list> 1.1192e+10, 1.3014e~
$ `Accounts Receivable, Net`                        <list> 1.1192e+10, 1.3014e~
$ `Notes Receivable, Net`                           <list> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,~
$ `Unbilled Revenues`                               <list> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,~
$ Inventories                                       <list> 7.17e+08, 7.4e+08, ~
```

Again when I compare *Income Statement* (MSFT_1) and *Balance Sheet* (MSFT_2) the data structure looks absolutely identical to me

```
> str(MSFT_1)
'data.frame':   696 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ acc_name : chr  "Revenue" "Sales & Services Revenue" "Financing Revenue" "Other Revenue" ...
 $ acc_value: num  5.84e+10 NA NA NA -1.22e+10 ...
 $ year     : int  2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 ...
```

and

```
> str(MSFT_2)
'data.frame':   1020 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ acc_name : chr  "Cash, Cash Equivalents & Short Term Investments" "Cash & Cash Equivalents" "Short Term Investments" "Accounts & Notes Receivable" ...
 $ acc_value: num  3.14e+10 6.08e+09 2.54e+10 1.12e+10 1.12e+10 ...
 $ year     : int  2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 ...
```

Does anybody can give me a hint, why the expansion doesn't work for the Balance Sheet?

Thank you & Best wishes

Comment: Can you make the problem reproducible by adding the code you're using? What are "some variables", how are you getting from MSFT_FY_Raw to MSFT_1, MSFT_2, MSFT_PL and MSFT_BS? The answer is likely to lie somewhere in there...

Comment: ok. I added the detaiils about the arguments used with the function call

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).